# Consultation on APEX and Cloud

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am given a project which is very small project for small clinic which may be contains of five departments reception or registration and billing, pharmacy, store, laboratory, payroll so far, and as you know most of the operations for this project would be like CRUD operations if we will take first module as example:

for the first department "Registration and billing "
there will be form which contains the details of the patient and then the billing part will contain the entry fee and then if the patient goes to Dr then goes to pharmacy his details should be there in the pharmacy page where the medicine that he is going to buy will be added to his profile and then print the receipt.

My questions now are:

1. Can apex do this project.
2. Can I use the bar code to get the product details.
3. Can I add figure print machine for the employees attendance.
4. Can I integrate apex with some pages from JSP in case if I have dynamic module needs more control driven mechanisms.

Questions related to apex with 11g XE and cloud:

1. Can I use apex and 11g xe for free and install them in server in my organization? If yes, so What are the limitations ?
2. If am going to deploy it on cloud shall they will use Oracle 11g XE or Oracle SE or EE, or it depends on my request ?
3. If I greed to start apex  and I would like to deploy it on cloud is there any requirements , like Do I have to first contact Oracle and ask them to give me the login to apex on cloud and work remotely , Or 
   Can first develop it here in my machine and then contact oracle and deploy it on cloud .

If apex is not recommended for such projects please tell me before I start , and I will replace it with Java EE6

Comment: One question per question, and only programming questions are on-topic here. The only questions that are programming related in what you wrote are much too broad/general/generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Can apex do this project.

Yes.

> 1. Can I use the bar code to get the product details.

Client-side interactions are notoriously tricky with web applications.  It you have a bar code reader which can turn [the barcode into JQuery](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-barcodelistener/) or something then yes.  But this will be the hardest part of the project.

> 1. Can I add figure print machine for the employees attendance.

Same as 2. Can your FPS do JQuery?

> 1. Can I integrate apex with some pages from JSP in case if I have dynamic module needs more control driven mechanisms.

By default Apex operates out of the http server in the database.  If you want to include Java Server Pages you need a separate web server and your architecture has just got way more complicated.  The good news is that Apex is capable of supporting pretty sophisticated interactions, so the chances that you'll need JSP are slight.

> 1. Can I use apex and 11g xe for free and install them in server in my organization?

Yes.  For limitations I suggest ion [you read the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18803/toc.htm#BABIECJA%20%22Oracle%20XE%2011g%20Licensing%20Restrictions%22s).

> 1. If am going to deploy it on cloud shall they will use Oracle 11g XE or Oracle SE or EE, or it depends on my request ?

What cloud?  "cloud" is just a generic term of remote hosting.  But generally the point about cloud is you get to choose.  Also, remember that the Oracle licensing will still apply: when you deploy Oracle SE or EE you will need to pay the Per CPU license, so be careful if you plump for something flexible such as AWS Elastic Cloud.

> 1. If I greed to start apex and I would like to deploy it on cloud is there any requirements

Again, what cloud?  Oracle don't host apps, so why would you need to contact them?  There are a load of companies which do specialise in host Apex apps.  [Find out more](http://apex.oracle.com/pls/otn/f?p=24793:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3a%3a).

(OTN does [offer workspaces](http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=4700:1:7997192222452183%3a%3a%3a%3a%3a) but purely for evaluating Apex, not for actually running  - or even developing - production systems).

---

> "I have several comments on your answer "

Your original questions rather strained the remit of SO, which is a programming site.  Your follow-up questions are utterly off-topic, as they are largely business questions and the answer to pretty much all of them is "it depends".

Dependencies include:

- budget
- available skill set
- privacy and data protection compliance
- number of users
- amount of data
- usage profile
- complexity of application
- on-site facilities
- reliability and availability requirements

If you don't know how to analyze these factors and use them to evaluate architectural solutions you really ought to hire somebody who can.  This is work which would be measured in hours, if not days, and is way beyond what you can reasonably expect people to do for you on a Q&A site.

Remember: the free advice you get from some random bloke on the internet is worth exactly what you paid for it.

Comment: First of all Thanks a lot for replaying dear I appreciate it .

Comment: I have serveral comments on your answer :
1-I understand from you that I can do the stuff like bar code reader and FPS but it needs lot of effort , but the important part that I can still do it . thanks god you got me relief .
2.Do you suggest me to use Oracle 11 XE  which is free to use it for such a small project to run a business and in future if the business growing I will expand to use Oracle 11g SE or EE.

Comment: 3.Is it a good idea to creat the application and upload it to one of these in the list  http://apex.oracle.com/pls/otn/f?p=24793:11:0:::::
whereas this application is just small business application which will serve a small clinic so my question is Shall I install and deploy it on the clinic it self by buying new server and hire a guy to take care of the server ? or Shall I deploy it on cloud as you listed them out .

Comment: 4. If you suggest me to upload it on cloud which one is recommended out of the list that you've just provided http://apex.oracle.com/pls/otn/f?p=24793:11:0:::::
and Do you have any idea how costly are they ?
5. Finally Do you recommend me to use apex for such applications or not , if you not , Can you suggest me with alternate?

Comment: Hi buddy I know what you mean and thanks a lot for your precious talk but as the matter of the fact I guess this is my first project, I mean I have developed but they were college projects which does not require any dependencies, and I am really sorry to put it this way .

Comment: Forgive me for putting in this way but do your employers know you have no practical experience?  That you are out of your depth?  Can you have a sensible discussion with them?